# Storing string in arrays in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I am attempting to write a method that changes one string to another one letter at a time. However, I never noticed in ruby that if you push a string variable to an array it seems to push the address of the string variable and not the string.

```
def mutate_my_strings(s1,s2)
  #your code here

  str1 = s1.to_s
  str2 = s2.chars
  ret = []

  puts str1
  ret.push(str1)

  s1.chars.each_with_index do |q,idx|
    str1[idx] = str2.shift    
    ret.push(str1)
  end
  return ret.join("\n")
end

mutate_my_strings("bubble gum", "turtle ham")
```

This output shows that the enumerable modifies the str1 but the out for the **puts** the string "bubble gum" turn into "turtle ham" This isn't so in the array. The entire string is modified in the array:

```
bubble gum
"tubble gum"
"tubble gum"
"turble gum"
"turtle gum"
"turtle gum"
"turtle gum"
"turtle gum"
"turtle hum"
"turtle ham"
"turtle ham"
=> "turtle ham\nturtle ham\nturtle ham\nturtle ham\nturtle ham\nturtle ham\nturtle ham\nturtle ham\nturtle ham\nturtle ham\nturtle ham"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `ret.push(str1)` with `ret.push(str1.dup)` to create a new string every time.

And here is a more elegant solution to the problem:

```
def mutate_strings(s1, s2)
  (0...s1.size).map { |i| s2[0..i] + s1[i+1..-1] }.join("\n")
end

puts(mutate_strings('bubble gum', 'turtle ham'))
```

Comment: Well done. My version was very similar but a few seconds too late.

Comment: That was amazizing you you taught me something I never thought of.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by adding:

```
ret.push(str1) to
ret.push(str1 * 1)
```

This creates a new pointer every iteration